# event emitting when trying to fetch data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create two node.js files. I am using event emitter module. When ever i try to search through the data i want to emit an event so that event is raised before my data is returned from the array of objects.

```
// event emitter file:
 var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
 var inherits = require('util').inherits;
  var _ = require('underscore');

  // Custom class 
  function EmployeeEmitter(args) {
  this.data = args;
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  }
  inherits(EmployeeEmitter, EventEmitter);

  EmployeeEmitter.prototype.lookupByLastName = function (name) {

         this.emit('lookupByLastName',name);

         if( _.where(data, {lastName:name}))
         {
           return _.where(data, {lastName:name})
         }

        else{

                return;
              }
            };
   module.exports.EmployeeEmitter = EmployeeEmitter;
```

Now this is my event emitter which i want to fire lookupbylastName when the user searches through the data. For testing it i have created another file where i am using event.on method.Unfortunately its' not running it gives me error i dont know wats going wrong.

```
      //Test file:
         var colors = require('colors');

         var EmployeeEmitter = require('./employeeEmitter').EmployeeEmitter;

          // Usage
       var data = [
        {id:1, firstName:'John',lastName:'Smith'},
        {id:2, firstName:'Jane',lastName:'Smith'},
         {id:3, firstName:'John',lastName:'Doe'}
        ];

      var employees = new EmployeeEmitter(data);
      employees.on('lookupByLastName', function (args) {
     });

     console.log("\nLookup by last name (Smith)".red);
     console.log(employees.lookupByLastName('Smith'));
```

Comment: what kind of error is it giving you ?

Comment: if( _.where(data, {lastName:name}))   it says data is not defined in my file one. How do i pass data which is defined in my test file.